# Update Node App in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, express, npm, azure-web-app-service

We have a node app running `express` with a couple proxies in a WAWS with 4 slots.

Is it possible to trigger an `npm update` without pushing new code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've built some type of automation into your app to call `npm update` programmatically, you'd either need to push new code, or do it manually via the console (`yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net`).

Comment: You may also be able to do it programmatically via the [Kudu Command API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#command).